# How to use insert into and join together

Tags: sql-server, join, insert

I am trying to do is I have 2 tables `t1` and `t2`. `t1` is the main table and info from `t2` is being inserted into `t1` on daily basis.

I am trying to use insert and join together so that all the matching data in `t1` and `t2` won't be inserted into `t1` again.

I want to insert only the unique items in table `t2` into `t1`.

Table T1:

```
Date                Details
-------------------------------
01-02-2021 11.02    completed
01-02-2021 01.30    cancelled
```

Table T2:

```
Date                Details
-------------------------------
01-02-2021 11.02    completed
01-02-2021 01.30    cancelled
02-03-2021 03.30    running
02-03-2021 05.30    failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `EXCEPT`

Example:

```
INSERT INTO T1( [Date], Details )
SELECT [Date], Details
FROM T2
EXCEPT -- This is equivalent to subtracting T1 records from T2 records
SELECT [Date], Details
FROM T1
```

You can also do it with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO T1( [Date], Details )
SELECT [Date], Details
FROM T2
    -- Add all of the columns that you want to match one.
    LEFT JOIN T1 ON T2.[Date] = T1.[Date] AND T2.Details = T1.Details
-- This ensures that only records that did not match T1 are returned.
WHERE T1.[Date] IS NULL
```

Left Join method is useful when you want to return additional columns (in the SELECT column list) on top of the columns you are matching tables on.

Except method is better suited if you want to filter tables on all of their output columns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.. this method worked out for me

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, if it has helped you solve your problem.